Can We do nikkah without wali when he's not marrying off his daughter?
I'm 24F i come from a strict family and I want to marry someone specific 26M. He is good in deen and in ikhlaq also can manage my expenses if I become his wife but the problem is my parents are not agreeing to marry me to him. I dont have any other proposals and they want me to wait years for a rich business man. Alhamdulillah I'm not thinking of commiting any sin but it feels like in the near future I wont be able to control my desires with him. We both want to get married ASAP
I have tried convincing my family even told them bluntly that i want to get married and start my own family but they are denying his proposal just because he is an avg looking man and not filthy rich.
Can we do nikkah ourselves with witnesses and imam without wali if my family doesn't marry me with in the next 2 years? I'm afraid if the age increases I'll also face fertility issues and making a family in a peaceful environment is my top most priority.
